# ECONNREFUSED when attempting to access Docker service in GitLab CI

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to access a `Docker` container which exposes an `Express` API (using `Docker Compose` services) in GitLab CI in order to run a number of tests against it.

I setup and instantiate the Docker services necessary as one task, then I attempt accessing it via `axios` requests in my tests. I have set `0.0.0.0` as the endpoint base.

However, I keep receiving the error:

```
[Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:3000]
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  st-sample:
    container_name: st-sample
    image: sample
    restart: always
    build: .
    expose:
      - "3000"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - /sampledb
    expose:
      - "27017"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

My `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - node
  - mongo
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - prepare_image
  - setup_application
  - test
  - teardown_application

prepare_image:
  stage: prepare_image
  script:
    - docker build -t sample .

setup_application:
  stage: setup_application
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d

test:
  image: node:latest
  stage: test
  allow_failure: true
  before_script:
    - npm install
  script:
    - npm test

teardown_application:
  stage: teardown_application
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml stop
```

Note that I also have registered the runner in my machine, giving it privileged permissions.

Locally everything works as expected - docker containers are initiated and are accessed for the tests.

However I am unable to do this via `GitLab CI`. The Docker containers build and get set up normally, however I am unable to access the exposed API.

I have tried many things, like setting the hostname for accessing the container, setting a static IP, using the container name etc, but to no success - I just keep receiving `ECONNREFUSED`.

I understand that they have their own network isolation strategy for security reasons, but I am just unable to expose the docker service to be tested.

Can you give an insight to this please? Thank you.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IP address that means "all interfaces"; in Docker it's important to _listen_ to "all interfaces" but it doesn't make sense to connect to it.  Do you have a [mcve] showing how you're setting up the containers and what environment is trying to connect to it?

Comment: @DavidMaze updated question, containing related files.

Comment: I'm guessing that firewall is blocking the connection to 3000 port in the runner. Is telnet working to 3000 port from the runner where the testcases are running, after the application starts running?

Comment: It is not firewall. I disabled it and checked all configurations. Nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out, following 4 days of reading, searching and lots of trial and error. The job running the tests was in a different container from the ones that exposed the API and the database.

I resolved this by creating a docker network in the device the runner was on:

```
sudo network create mynetwork
```

Following that, I set the network to the `docker-compose.yml` file, with external config, and associated both services with it:

```
  st-sample:
    # ....
  networks:
    - mynetwork

  mongo:
    # ....
    networks:
      - mynetwork


networks:
  mynetwork:
    external: true
```

Also, I created a custom docker image including tests (name: `test`),
and in `gitlab-ci.yml`, I setup the job to run it within `mynetwork`.

```
docker run --network=mynetwork test
```

Following that, the containers/services were accessible by their names along each other, so I was able to run tests against `http://st-sample`.

It was a long journey to figure it all out, but it was well-worth it - I learned a lot!